# Как отобразить текущие позиции в scrollBar или textView в recyclerView?

Tags: android, recyclerview, прокрутка, position, android-scrollview

Имеется 2-строчный горизонтальный список с итемами, и надо отобразить текущую позиции как минимум 2 итемов при прокрутке (непринципиально в scrollbar'e или textview'ке). Реализация адаптеров и всего прочего стандартная.

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        inetItems = new ArrayList<>();

        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
        gson = gsonBuilder.create();

        fetchPosts();

        button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageLogcat);
        gifView = (GifView) findViewById(R.id.gifView);
        gifView = new GifView(this);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.indicator);


        final RecyclerView rvItems = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvItems);

        adapter = new ItemsAdapter(getApplicationContext(), inetItems);

        rvItems.setAdapter(adapter);


        final GridLayoutManager layoutManager2 = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        layoutManager2.scrollToPosition(0);

        rvItems.setLayoutManager(layoutManager2);

        rvItems.setHasFixedSize(true);

        SnapHelper snapHelper = new LinearSnapHelper();
        snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(rvItems);

        ItemOffsetDecoration itemDecoration = new ItemOffsetDecoration(this, R.dimen.item_offset);
        rvItems.addItemDecoration(itemDecoration);

        rvItems.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(this, rvItems, new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position) {
                //Values are passing to activity & to fragment as well
//                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Single Click on position: " + (position + 1),
//                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Items intentItem = inetItems.get(position);
                int userId = Integer.parseInt(intentItem.getUserId());
                int id = Integer.parseInt(intentItem.getId());

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("userId", userId);
                intent.putExtra("id", id);
                startActivity(intent);

            }

            @Override
            public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {
//                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Long press on position: " + position,
//                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }));

rvItems.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState)
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                int firstVisibleItemPosition = ((GridLayoutManager) (rvItems.getLayoutManager())).findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

                //textView.setText(String.valueOf(firstVisibleItemPosition));

                int offset = recyclerView.computeVerticalScrollOffset();
                int extent = recyclerView.computeVerticalScrollExtent();
                int range = recyclerView.computeVerticalScrollRange();

                int percentage = (int)(100.0 * offset / (float)(range - extent));

                String x = "13/14";

                textView.setText(String.valueOf(x));
            }
        });
    }
```

[image: позиция в recyclerview]

Заранее благодарен.